# Reverse proxy: forward all requests to sub-path of upstream app

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy.

I have an upstream call `app_demo`. How do I route all incoming requests to the upstream using a sub-path as root? For example, if the incoming is to `/page1`, it should be forwarded to `/module1/page1` in the upstream app. That is, all incoming paths will be "rooted" at `/module1` in the upstream. All `/*` goes to `/module1/*`.

Is such a configuration possible?

`app_demo` is fully functional web site, serving a bunch of pages, from its root as well as via a path under `/module`. So for example, `app_demo` would serve the following urls:

```
/welcome
/aboutus
/contactus
/module/page1
/module/page2
```

Basically, I want the server currently being configured in nginx to see only the urls under `/module1/` and not to be able to access `/welcome`, `/aboutus`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_demo/module1/;
}
```